# Do not allow to select more then 'n' in total jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to create a function where the user should not be able to select more than 'n' in value from multiple select options. In my case, I want to restrict the user to select a maximum of 4 in value.

HTML:

```html
<ul class="numberOfElementsList">
   <li>0</li>
   <li class="active">1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
<select>
<ul class="numberOfElementsList">
   <li>0</li>
   <li class="active">1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="numberOfElementsList">
   <li>0</li>
   <li class="active">1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
if(numBer > 4) {
        alert('You can not select more then 4.');
      } else if(numBer == 4) {
        $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li.active').nextAll('li').hide();
        $(this).nextAll('li').hide();
        $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li.active').nextAll('li').hide();
      } else if(numBer == 3) {
        if (indexNum == 3){
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(2)').nextAll('li').hide();
            $(this).nextAll('li.active').nextAll('li').hide();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li::nth-child(2)').nextAll('li').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li.active, li:last-child').nextAll('li').hide();
            $(this).nextAll('li.active').nextAll('li').hide();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li.active, li:last-child').nextAll('li').hide();
            
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(3)').prevAll('li').show();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(3)').prevAll('li').show();
        }
      } else if(numBer == 2) {
        if (indexNum == 2){
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(3)').nextAll('li').hide();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:last-child').hide();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(3)').nextAll('li').hide();
          
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(4)').prevAll('li').show();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(4)').prevAll('li').show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(3)').nextAll('li').hide();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:last-child').hide();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(3)').nextAll('li').hide();
          
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(4)').prevAll('li').show();
            $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li:nth-child(4)').prevAll('li').show();
        }
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').nextAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li').nextAll('li').show();
        $(this).prevAll('li').show();
        $(this).nextAll('li').show();
        $(this).closest('.breedOptionsWrapper').prevAll('.breedOptionsWrapper').find('li').nextAll('li').show();
      }
```

Here I want the user to restrict at max 4. Like if the user selects 1-2-1, 1-1-2, 3-1-0 combination, or any other combination then the other options values should be disabled. I have tried many things but not working.

Thank You

Comment: Can you please share one of that *many things* you tried? [ask], [mcve]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan please let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: Seems clearer now. Thank you

Comment: So, what's wrong with the code you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get a `tot` value using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- Loop all your option Elements and set the `hidden` and `disabled`
  attributes  if `parseFloat(opt.value) > (maxTot - tot)`

```js
const $prod = $(".prod");
const $opts = $prod.find("option");
const maxTot = 4;   // Set here the desired total

$prod.on("change", function() {

  const tot = [...$prod].reduce((tot, sel) => {
    tot += parseFloat(sel.value);
    return tot;
  }, 0);
  
  $opts.each((i, opt) => {
    const is_hide = parseFloat(opt.value) > (maxTot - tot);
    opt.disabled = is_hide;
    opt.hidden = is_hide;
  });
 
});
```

```html
<select class="prod">
  <option value="0">Product 0</option>
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>
<select class="prod">
  <option value="0">Product 0</option>
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>
<select class="prod">
  <option value="0">Product 0</option>
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  <option value="3">Product 3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```